# How to check if a string can be exhausted by regex matches?

Tags: java, regex

So the problem is to determine if every character in a string would be included in a match of a particular regex.  Or, to state it differently, if the set of all of the character positions that could be included in some match of a particular regex includes all the character positions in the string.

My thought is to do something like this:

```
boolean matchesAll(String myString, Matcher myMatcher){
    boolean matched[] = new boolean[myString.size()];
    for(myMatcher.reset(myString); myMatcher.find();)
        for(int idx = myMatcher.start(); idx < myMatcher.end(); idx++)
            matched[idx] = true;

    boolean allMatched = true;
    for(boolean charMatched : matched)
        allMatched &= charMatched;

    return allMatched
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, however?

Also, as I was writing this, it occured to me that that would not do what I want in cases like

```
matchesAll("abcabcabc", Pattern.compile("(abc){2}").matcher()); //returns false
```

because `Matcher` only tries to match starting at the end of the last match.  I want it to return true, because if you start the matcher at position 3, it could include the third `abc` in a match.

```
boolean matchesAll(String myString, Matcher myMatcher){

    boolean matched[] = new boolean[myString.size()];
    boolean allMatched = true;

    for(int idx = 0; idx < myString.size() && myMatcher.find(idx);
            idx = myMatcher.start() + 1) {

        for(int idx2 = myMatcher.start(); idx2 < myMatcher.end(); idx2++)
            matched[idx2] = true;
    }

    boolean allMatched = true;
    for(boolean charMatched : matched)
        allMatched &= charMatched;

    return allMatched;
}
```

Is there any way to make this code better, faster, or more readable?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve?  Can you discuss why you want to do this?

Comment: Its just a programming excersize, from school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
private static boolean fullyCovered(final String input,
    final Pattern pattern)
{
    // If the string is empty, check that it is matched by the pattern
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return pattern.matcher(input).find();

    final int len = input.length();
    // All initialized to false by default
    final boolean[] covered = new boolean[len];

    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        // Try and match at this index:
        if (!matcher.find(index)) {
            // if there isn't a match, check if this character is already covered;
            // if no, it's a failure
            if (!covered[index])
                return false;
            // Otherwise, continue
            continue;
        }
        // If the match starts at the string index, fill the covered array
        if (matcher.start() == index)
            setCovered(covered, index, matcher.end());
    }

    // We have finished parsing the string: it is fully covered.
    return true;
}

private static void setCovered(final boolean[] covered,
    final int beginIndex, final int endIndex)
{
    for (int i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        covered[i] = true;
}
```

It will probably not be any faster to execute, but I surmise it is easier to read ;) Also, `.find(int)` resets the matcher, so this is safe.

Comment: The problem with that is the same as the problem with the first method I mentioned, that it won't perform it on matches that overlap with each other.

Comment: Are you sure regexes are the tool you are looking for, then? How do you proceed with regexes matching empty strings?

Comment: if they match empty strings, those empty strings it is matching aren't containing any of the strings characters, are they?  And if the string the regex is applied to is empty, my second method already returns true.

Comment: I think I have found a solution ;) But it will take some time to code!

Comment: See edit. It is another solution, a little more elegant, maybe not faster, though. It shortcuts in the false case.

Comment: Note that there are rooms for optimization: for instance, in the last test of the main loop, if `.hitEnd()` is true you can directly return true. And a few other things.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 answers for you, although I am not sure I understand the question right.

1. Call Pattern.matcher(str2match).matches() method instead of find(). In one shot a true return value will tell you if the entire string is matched.
2. Prepend the reg exp by "^" (beginning of string) and add a "$" at the end (for end of string) before "Pattern.compile(str)"-ing the regex.

The 2 solutions can go together, too. An example class follows - you can copy it into AllMatch.java, compile it with "javac AllMatch.java" and run it as "java AllMatch" (I assume you have "." in your CLASSSPATH). Just pick the solution you find is more elegant :) Happy New Year!

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

public class AllMatch {

```
private Pattern pattern;

public AllMatch (String reStr) {
    pattern = Pattern.compile ("^" + reStr + "$");
}

public boolean checkMatch (String s) {
    return pattern.matcher(s).matches();
}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    int n = args.length;
    String  rexp2Match = (n > 0) ? args[0] : "(abc)+",
        testString = (n > 1) ? args[1] : "abcabcabc",
        matchMaker = new AllMatch (rexp2Match)
                .checkMatch(testString) ? "" : "un";
    System.out.println ("[AllMatch] match " + matchMaker +
                "successful");
    }
```

}

Comment: I'm not actually testing whether the regex matches the whole string, as in `String.matches(String regex)` but rather if every character in the string is included in at least one match of the regex.